# Проблема с парсером

Tags: java

Никогда раньше не интересовался парсингом сайтов, но сейчас необходимо спарсить страницу вк. Написал такой код, который, как я понимаю, должен выводить Online. Но он вообще ничего не выводит. В чем проблема? Ошибок не выдает

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://vk.com/id94283688").get();

    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();

    Elements h4Elements = doc.getElementsByAttributeValue("class", "profile_online");

    h4Elements.forEach(h4Element -> {
        Element element = h4Element.child(0);
        strings.add(element.text());
    });

    for (String s :strings) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }

}
```

Вот этот элемент:

```
<h4 class="profile_online"><div id="profile_online_lv">Online<b class="mob_onl profile_mob_onl unshown" id="profile_mobile_online" onmouseover="mobileOnlineTip(this, {mid: cur.oid, right: 1})" onclick="mobilePromo(); "></b></div> </h4>
```

PS: я новичок и не обладаю большими знаниями в программировании

Comment: Дебажить пробовали? Что находится в `doc`, что в `h4Elements`? Очевидно, если код ничего не выводит, то `h4Elements` не содержит элементов.

Comment: А вообще правильнее воспользоваться VK API, а не скачивать страницу.

Comment: Я не нашел документацию по ней, только в android

Comment: vk api: https://vk.com/dev/users.get, поле `online`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что у Вас пустой `h4Elements`.

Для получения необходимого, можете воспользоваться, например `div#profile_online_lv`.

**Upd.** Посмотрите, что у Вас находится в `doc`. Потом установите корректный **User Agent** и снова посмотрите, что находится в `doc`.

**Upd 1.** Можете воспользоваться методом:

```
static boolean isOnline(String url) throws IOException {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    if(doc.text().indexOf("Online") != -1)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Но учтите, что есть страницы, содержимое которых *недоступно без авторизации*. Для таких страниц Вы будете получать `false`. Хотя в действительности это может быть и не так.

Это Вам как пример, далеко не очень хороший, но все же.

Comment: Попробовал так: Element element2 = doc.getElementsByAttributeValue("id", "profile_online_lv").get(0);


    strings.add(element2.text()); Выдает npe

Comment: А что такое user agent?

Comment: @Nick, Ну не приводить же мне Вам цитату по первой ссылке из поисковой выдачи?! Почитайте, что такое user agent, а потом посмотрите в сторону метода `Jsoup.userAgent(...)`. На единственно верное решение не претендую, но оно работает.

Comment: То есть нужно написать вот так ? Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://vk.com/zhenya_silver").userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.80 Safari/537.36").get();

Comment: @Nick, Ну да, что-то подобное.

Comment: Не всегда показывает правильно

Comment: @Nick, Смотрите **Upd 1.** к моему ответу.

Comment: Чуть позже добавлю нормально работающую версию.

Comment: Спасибо, попробовал с 15 людьми - 12 правильно. Спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 0):

Мне было необходимо проверить online ли человек. Поменял код на такой:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://vk.com/id94283688").get();

        Element element2 = doc.getAllElements().get(0);

        if (element2.text().contains("Online")) {
            System.out.println("Online");
        } else {
            System.out.println("No");
        }
```

Вроде все работает!

Comment: Ключевое слово -- **вроде**. Попробуйте прочекать другие страницы.

Comment: На некоторых пишет No, но я сомневаюсь, что он корректно работает... Как сделать более точно?

Comment: Ваши сомнения вполне обоснованы. Почитайте мой пост. Особенно про user agent.